# Change iframe width and height by script

Tags: iframe

I am opening a secure url in iframe from the non secure url. In this, there is a submit button when user click on it iframe content is changed but the iframe size is remain same.
But when i choose the all url either secure or non secure, I am able to resize the content with some other function.

```
parent.$('fancybox-wrap').setStyle({'height':'700px'});
parent.$('fancybox-content').setStyle({'height':'690px'});
```

but when I use different url (secure iframe url and non secure parent url) it produces an error (permission denied).

Can any one tell me any idea about this?

Comment: Are your secure & non-secure URLs using same domain? eg. http://www.mysite.com/some-page & https://www.mysite.com/secure-page or is the secure one on something completely different?

Comment: no my domain is same but i am using diffrent pages